# repositioning hyperlink next to lightning:textbox description

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, hyperlink

when I add styling to reposition a hyperlink next to a lightning components label, it seems to lose its functionality and no longer redirects,

```
<lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12">              

    <lightning:formattedUrl label="go to help" 
                                               target="_blank" value="https://www.google.com" />
        <lightning:textarea name="Description" required="true" value="{!v.textAreaValue}" placeholder="" label="Description" minlength="25" maxlength="32000" 
         messageWhenTooLong="A maximum of 32000 characters are allowed." messageWhenTooShort=" " messageWhenValueMissing="Description Required"
         onchange="{!c.itemsChange}" aura:id="field-required" onblur="{!c.checkSomething}"/>
</lightning:layoutItem>
```

Style:

```
.THIS lightning-formatted-url > a{
    color: #026bc8;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5rem;
    margin-top: 0.2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

It seems to lose its functionality, how does one fix this?
[image]

Comment: N.B. this technique looks like a bit of a hack, so if I were you, I'd test it in all possible environments (mobile, community, lex, etc) to make sure it doesn't break anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The later elements are physically over the earlier elements because of the repositioning. To fix this, move your anchor up in the z-index:

## css

```
.THIS lightning-formatted-url > a{
  ...
  z-index: 1;
  ...
}
```

Comment: its exactly what i did to "fix" this +1